# Mark areas over an image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my problem is: I have an image and want to mark some areas over it and store the coordinates. Something like tagging someone in a photo on facebook. The user should be able to mark squares and polygons.

Someone knows any library that could help me to do this? May be something in jquery.

tks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code you have a specific problem with?

Comment: @robertc actually the image storage and view is done.  what I need know is something in JavaScript to make the markings over the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently found this: http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Seems to be very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery and HTML5
[Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) is a wonderful plugin to work with

Comment: Jcrop is really nice!! But It only works with squares, and I need to make polygons too. =\